# How can I modify a GeoTiff coverage to allow WCS slicing?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, wcs

This is a rephrasing of an earlier question that I have deleted.

I have a collection of GeoTiffs that form a mosaic on a GeoServer. These files contain a simple raster of terrain elevation data. I want to be able to use the WCS slicing function to get a single point, by slicing in the X-axis and Y-axis. Problem is that such axes are not defined in the coverage. It appears to only have a single `GRAY_INDEX` axis.

I've been searching for two days for a solution, but this doesn't seem like a commonly discussed topic as keywords only return a handful of results and few of them are even remotely relevant.

Here's the coverage description, in case it helps with finding an answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wcs:CoverageDescriptions
  xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1
  http://***.***.***.***:****/geoserver/schemas/wcs/1.1.1/wcsDescribeCoverage.xsd">
    <wcs:CoverageDescription>
        <ows:Title>nh_riks_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>Generated from ImageMosaic</ows:Abstract>
        <ows:Keywords>
            <ows:Keyword>nh_riks_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff</ows:Keyword>
            <ows:Keyword>WCS</ows:Keyword>
            <ows:Keyword>ImageMosaic</ows:Keyword>
        </ows:Keywords>
        <wcs:Identifier>swe:elev</wcs:Identifier>
        <wcs:Domain>
            <wcs:SpatialDomain>
                <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" dimensions="2">
                    <ows:LowerCorner>7.39871779882174 54.79672820200517</ows:LowerCorner>
                    <ows:UpperCorner>27.54744509481714 69.39062671463897</ows:UpperCorner>
                </ows:BoundingBox>
                <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3006" dimensions="2">
                    <ows:LowerCorner>6100000.000000001 199999.99999999994</ows:LowerCorner>
                    <ows:UpperCorner>7700000.000000002 1000000.0000000001</ows:UpperCorner>
                </ows:BoundingBox>
                <wcs:GridCRS>
                    <wcs:GridBaseCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3006</wcs:GridBaseCRS>
                <wcs:GridType>urn:ogc:def:method:WCS:1.1:2dGridIn2dCrs</wcs:GridType>
                    <wcs:GridOrigin>200025.0 7699975.0</wcs:GridOrigin>
                    <wcs:GridOffsets>50.0 0.0 0.0 -50.0</wcs:GridOffsets>
                    <wcs:GridCS>urn:ogc:def:cs:OGC:0.0:Grid2dSquareCS</wcs:GridCS>
                </wcs:GridCRS>
            </wcs:SpatialDomain>
        </wcs:Domain>
        <wcs:Range>
            <wcs:Field>
                <wcs:Identifier>contents</wcs:Identifier>
                <wcs:Definition>
                    <ows:AllowedValues>
                        <ows:Range>
                            <ows:MinimumValue>-Infinity</ows:MinimumValue>
                            <ows:MaximumValue>Infinity</ows:MaximumValue>
                        </ows:Range>
                    </ows:AllowedValues>
                </wcs:Definition>
                <wcs:InterpolationMethods>
                    <wcs:Default>nearest neighbor</wcs:Default>
                </wcs:InterpolationMethods>
                <wcs:Axis identifier="Bands">
                    <wcs:AvailableKeys>
                        <wcs:Key>GRAY_INDEX</wcs:Key>
                    </wcs:AvailableKeys>
                </wcs:Axis>
            </wcs:Field>
        </wcs:Range>
        <wcs:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3006</wcs:SupportedCRS>
        <wcs:SupportedCRS>EPSG:3006</wcs:SupportedCRS>
        <wcs:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326</wcs:SupportedCRS>
        <wcs:SupportedCRS>EPSG:4326</wcs:SupportedCRS>
        <wcs:SupportedFormat>image/png</wcs:SupportedFormat>
        <wcs:SupportedFormat>image/jpeg</wcs:SupportedFormat>
        <wcs:SupportedFormat>image/tiff</wcs:SupportedFormat>
    </wcs:CoverageDescription>
</wcs:CoverageDescriptions>
```

This is my attempt at using slice on the coverage:

```
<wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0 ../../wcsAll.xsd"
  service="WCS" version="2.0.1">
    <wcs:CoverageId>swe:elev</wcs:CoverageId>
    <wcs:DimensionSlice>
        <wcs:Dimension>x</wcs:Dimension>
        <wcs:SlicePoint>588000</wcs:SlicePoint>
    </wcs:DimensionSlice>
    <wcs:DimensionSlice>
        <wcs:Dimension>y</wcs:Dimension>
        <wcs:SlicePoint>6228000</wcs:SlicePoint>
    </wcs:DimensionSlice>
    <wcs:Output store="true" format="image/tiff">
        <wcs:GridCRS>
            <wcs:GridBaseCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3006</wcs:GridBaseCRS>
            <wcs:GridType>urn:ogc:def:method:WCS:1.1:2dGridIn2dCrs</wcs:GridType>
            <wcs:GridOrigin>200025 7699975</wcs:GridOrigin>
            <wcs:GridOffsets>50 0 0 -50</wcs:GridOffsets>
            <wcs:GridCS>urn:ogc:def:cs:OGC:0.0:Grid2dSquareCS</wcs:GridCS>
        </wcs:GridCRS>
    </wcs:Output>
</wcs:GetCoverage>
```

The server returns an error that the axis 'x' doesn't exist.

Comment: With WCS 2.0 it might go by making a request with so that you give only one value as a SUBSET range for X and Y. See DescribeCoverage for seeing what are the real axis names for your coverage.

Comment: Could you elaborate? From what I see from DescribeCoverage is that the only axis name is `GRAY_INDEX` (I already pasted the result into the question).

Comment: Slicing is an operation of the WCS, not something that can be enabled in the data

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the data need to be a certain structure? I found out about slicing from your answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91863/90828. I tried to do a similar GetCoverage, but the server responds that there is no axis with the name 'x'. I'm asking if I can somehow modify the data so that it has two axes 'x' and 'y' that I can slice in, rather than just that strange `GRAY_INDEX` thing.

Comment: Spatial dimensions come from the coordinate system of the output. If it is EPSG:4326 then there are automatically axis for latitude and longitude. You don't need to add them through the configuration, nor can you take them away.

Comment: Then according to http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3006/html/ the axes should be named 'x' and 'y', correct? But when I attempt to slice in those axes the server responds with that they don't exist. I updated my question with my slicing attempt. It was adapted from the example in nmtoken's answer, which I linked to in an earlier comment.

Comment: You must slice with the axis names that you read from the DescribeCoverarage of your server. If you show the WCS 2.0.1 DescribeCoverage I can have a look.

Comment: The result of DescribeCoverage is already pasted in the question. I cannot find any axis names. Unless `GRAY_INDEX` is it, but I don't think it is.
Is the problem that I'm doing DescribeCoverage with WCS 1.1.1? Will I get the information I need if I do DescribeCoverage with WCS 2.0.1? I didn't do that because I got an error related to the RestSharp library we use when I tried that. I could perhaps try to find a way round that if you think it would help.

Comment: What you want to do is possible with older versions as well but I do not remember how, exactly and I don't bother to play with WCS 1.x any more.  Let's hope some other user jumps in and helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "nurc__Img_Sample" coverage
http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=DescribeCoverage&coverageID=nurc__Img_Sample

Find the axis names

```
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Envelope srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326" axisLabels="Lat Long" uomLabels="Deg Deg" srsDimension="2">
<gml:lowerCorner>20.7052 -130.85168</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>54.1141 -62.0054</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope>
</gml:boundedBy>
```

Ok, the names are "Lat" and "Long". Make a query with a slice point by using subsets like

> &subset=Long("-100")&subset=Lat("22")

Send the query and you will get back a GeoTIFF that contains one pixel

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&coverageid=nurc__Img_Sample&subset=Long(%22-100%22)&subset=Lat(%2222%22)

Verify with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo nurc__Img_Sample.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: nurc__Img_Sample.tif
Size is 1, 1
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GeoTransform =
  22.0460254180602, 0, -0.05586772575250837
  -99.96540382502543, 0.07003690742624616, 0
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (      22.046,     -99.965) ( 22d 2'45.69"E, 99d57'55.45"S)
Lower Left  (      21.990,     -99.965) ( 21d59'24.57"E, 99d57'55.45"S)
Upper Right (      22.046,     -99.895) ( 22d 2'45.69"E, 99d53'43.32"S)
Lower Right (      21.990,     -99.895) ( 21d59'24.57"E, 99d53'43.32"S)
Center      (      22.018,     -99.930) ( 22d 1' 5.13"E, 99d55'49.39"S)
Band 1 Block=16x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=16x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=16x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
```

It looks that the longitude value 100 that we used in the request is not inside the returned pixel. That may be a bug.